# Why do we require a final evaluation in k-fold cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, modeling

I am aware that there are many answers to many posts on this topic (see: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set),[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225949/do-we-need-a-test-set-when-using-k-fold-cross-validation), [3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/121105/what-is-the-point-of-final-test-set-in-k-fold-cross-validation)). Generally, the common answer is that this is 'best practice', it avoids 'data leakage' or overfitting.

Is there a scientific basis and proof to these claims? One academic source mentionned was page 222 of this [book](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/NoHesitations/BookAdvanced.pdf), but I cannot see why an absolute measure of fit, like the R2, should be calculated on a final testing set.

Similarly, I looked at this [paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245919898466#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20because,independent%20holdout%20set.) which only mentions in the discussion the potential need for a final testing dataset.

Comment: The answer is always the same, because you do not want your model to use any data from the test set when evaluating a model, since this will inevitably lead to overly optimistic results. That's why you do your k-fold (or something else, repeatedly), and then test at the end on a separate set.

Comment: I've read that answer but is there a proof that "this will inevitably lead to overly optimistic results"? Why would it "inevitably lead to overly optimistic results", since you computed our measure of fit e.g. R2 on the test data that's part of the k-fold process?

Comment: Because the model was trained on the test set data as well, and so it will probably perform better on this set than if it didn't see it at all. There are also many other reasons for why this might happen, testing multiple times (inadvertently or not) on the same set until you find a model which (seemingly) performs better on the test set. For an analogy, consider the case where you have to study for a subject for which you have to take a test in the end, would you perform better if you would see said test before the actual test?

Comment: Of course it depends on the actual method that is cross-validated whether results will indeed be overoptimistic. In principle you could define a method in which information from test data is used in a way that it makes matters worse, and in that case data leakage will not normally result in overoptimism. But we would normally use methods in which such information improves results, and then data leakage means we use better information in CV than we would have in a real situation with new data.

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily or even usually true that "the model was trained on the test set data as well."  The point of a training-set/test-set split is precisely to see how a model trained on one set of data will perform on another.  I wouldn't modify such a model to better fit the test set.  I think only under special circumstances would an additional, "validation" set be needed.  However, I see the value of choosing a final model (not judging its performance) based on all available data.

Comment: @rolando2 +1, thank you.  I was confused by user2974951 answer. Under which circumstances do you think a validation test is needed?

Comment: The example given -- "testing multiple times (inadvertently or not) on the same set until you find a model which (seemingly) performs better on the test set" -- sounds as if it could bias upward the performance measures.  It would make the erstwhile test set more like a training set and would require a new, unbiased test of model performance.

Comment: Reasonable people disagree; I think I am in the minority on this question but I lean towards your point of view.

Comment: I think there's some confusion: cross validation is used both as an accurate measure of test set accuracy (no independent test necessary) and for hyperparameter optimisation, in which case an independent data set is required for estimating the test set accuracy. infact nested crossvalidation can be used